# Meteor: Allow only one client instance per user

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to prevent the user to open the Meteor website in two tabs or browsers?

I am trying to create a card game in Meteor, and I would like to "catch" if the user tries to open the page in another tab or browser and just warn him that another client instance is already opened and maybe give him/her the option to logout in all instances, etc.

I've googled already, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the users are required to log in:

- Save the connection to a `Connections` collection, along with user id. (or the roomId to the profile itself, depending on your schema)
- Remove the connection on disconnect
- on each new connection, see if the user id already exists in the `Connections` collection

If the users do not have to log in:

- Save the connection to a `Connections` collection (along with user IP)
- Remove the connection on disconnect
- on each new connection, see if the IP address already exists in the `Connections` collection

An example of using onConnection in the wild (note I don't disallow multiple connections, but that'd just be another 5 lines of code): https://github.com/mattkrick/react-tac-toe/blob/master/server/gameState.jsx#L13

The docs (ie how to capture ip address): http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_onconnection

Comment: Is the IP enough? Can't users potentially have the same IP, if they share a router or some such?

I used your suggestion and combined it with mizzao:user-status suggested by Michael below and it saves/deletes to/from the Connections collection just fine. I am now trying to figure out how to force the second connection to logout and go to a special explanations page?

Comment: you wont have an IP clash from 2 unique devices (ultra rare exceptions being running out of ipv4 space, or using a hub to replicate packets to all devices). what could happen is the same device accesses the server twice (eg 2 tabs open). If this happens, just follow bullet point #3. check the table for the ip address. if it exists, redirect to an explanation page & return.

Comment: yes, I know that I should follow #3, I am just not sure how to do that... how to redirect the client from the Meteor.onConnection server event... but I am trying something that I think should do the trick...

Comment: depends on what router you use, if you use one at all. I like redux-simple-router, but since flowrouter is the defacto standard, it'd be something like: `FlowRouter.go('/multi-login-error');` 
https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowroutergopathdef-params-queryparams

Comment: Yup, I had the same idea :) I made a isDuplicate method in the router, added this check and it works like a charm, for two tabs, both go to the "duplicate" page, and as soon as one tab is closed, the other goes back to the application :) I LOVE THIS THING :D Thanks man!

Comment: @PredragStojadinović : How did you solve your problem? I am having Meteor 1.4 right now, I want the same functionality, can you please help me?

Comment: @ankur-soni: exactly as the above answer specifies

Answer (score 1):

There's a very handy package for tracking IP address and sessions across devices: [mizzao:user-status](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status). This adds a key to the user's document (that you will need to publish to the client) detailing their connections, whether they are active or not, the IP address, even the user agent. You can even observe changes to this key to detect from the first session that the user has also connected a second session or vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, I am already using that package to handle online users, however, it only shows "online: true" and if the user just opens another tab, or another browser, the IP is the same, the online flag remains true, only the lastLogin date changes... which can change if he simply refreshed the page... so, my problem is at which point to check for the "online: true" flag in other to know whether this is a double join or simply a refresh?

Comment: @Michel: I humbly request you to put light on what Predrag has asked in above comment. I want to ensure only one connection is open for a user, so it must forbid me to open site on other tab or other browser. any suggestions?

Comment: On the server look at the `UserStatus` collection - it has one document per active connection. You can implement a callback on login `UserStatus.events.on("connectionLogin",....` that searches the `UserStatus` collection for the current user. If you find him/her more than once then take action.

Comment: @MichelFloyd: What exactly you mean by "If you find him/her more than once then take action". How can I count them?

Comment: @MichelFloyd: Got it! I guess you meant by something that I have posted below as a peice of code.

Answer (score 0):

As MichelFloyd suggest in above chat. I followed his instructions and tried below stuff.

Add package using

**$ meteor add mizzao:user-status**

**Code:**

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user){
  UserStatus.events.on("connectionLogin", function(fields) {
    $count = UserStatus.connections.find({userId : fields.userId}).count();
    console.log('Total log ins : ' + $count);
  });
});
```

1. When I opened multiple browser being logged in, the count went on increasing and when when I closed browsers one by one, count went on decreasing.
2. You can use this count to monitor number of users logging in.

You can [follow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982528/how-to-make-meteor-user-field-reactive) to view entire scenario solved.